# Are Yii sessions and PHP sessions cross-compatible?

Tags: php, session, yii, amazon-web-services

In Yii, while looking at the source code for CWebUser::logout, I've noticed that they use `Yii::app()->getSession()->destroy()` instead of the usual PHP `session_destroy`.

Doing a bit of research I saw that Yii has a class called `CHttpSession` with its own methods to store data.

This got me thinking - are they cross-compatible? Is `CHttpSession` just a nice wrapper? Or is it an all or nothing process?

In my custom code, I've been using `$_SESSION` to do all of my session-related stuff. While in things generated by Yii, I assume that it uses `CHttpSession`. Is it a problem to use both and mix them up?

I am now in the process of moving my session handling to AWS DynamoDB (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/docs/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.rst), and before I add this additional layer, I want to make sure everything is compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CHttpSession`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession) is a nifty OO wrapper for php sessions. The underlying implementation uses php's session methods. Here's a snippet of part of the code for [`CHttpSession::open()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#open-detail):

```
public function open()
{
    if($this->getUseCustomStorage())
        @session_set_save_handler( array($this,'openSession'),array($this,'closeSession'),array($this,'readSession'),array($this,'writeSession'),array($this,'destroySession'),array($this,'gcSession'));

    @session_start();
```

For Yii convention, always use `CHttpSession` instead of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Good. Do you think then it can have any effect on the link I included?  I am changing the custom storage, but I'm not handling the code that does it, AWS does it for me. It should still work automatically right? https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/docs/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.rst

Comment: I'm not sure about it working automatically or what effect it may have. You may have to override the `openSession` method in a subclass to include the github snippets, and use this class as your session wrapper. Happy testing.

Comment: You can use Database based session to recover that. Its really simple.
Just put 
'session' => array(
            'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
            //'timeout' => 86400,
        ),
on config/main.php components

Answer (score 1):

You can use Database based session to recover that. Its really simple. Just put

```
'session' => array( 
                'class'=>'CDbHttpSession', 
                 'connectionID' => 'db' 
),
```

on config/main.php components